# How to create an importable Swift library with swiftc

Tags: swift, module, package, static-libraries

Wondering how to create a library so that I can do this:

```
// in MyProject/main.swift
import MyLibrary

let x = MyLibrary("foo")
...
```

Currently I am just compiling a swift file like this:

```
swiftc main.swift
```

I have a `Package.swift` as well, so it ends up generating a `main` file at `./main`.

Wondering how to do this locally, so I can build a local module/library `MyLibrary`, and use it locally in another project `MyProject`.

Comment: Are you using the Swift Package Manager or do you just have a `Package.swift` file?

Comment: I just have a `Package.swift` file with ``import PackageDescription; let package = Package(name:  "MyLibrary")`` in it.

Comment: Are you planning to use this library on macOS/Linux only or were you thinking of using iOS/tvOS/watchOS as well?

Comment: Just macos, but knowing both would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend switching to the [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/) if you are only planning to make this library available on macOS or Linux. Currently, SPM only works on macOS and Linux, not on iOS/tvOS/watchOS. However, it makes library distribution much easier.

To convert your library to the Swift Package Manager, its source files need to be in this directory structure:

```
MyLibrary-package
├── Sources
│   └── MyLibrary
│       ├── File1.swift
│       └── File2.swift
├── Tests
│   └── MyLibraryTests
│       └── MyLibraryTests.swift
└── Package.swift
```

The top level folder can be called whatever you want, but the `Sources` and `Tests` folders should keep their names. Where I have `MyLibrary`, you can put the name of your package, but **it must match the name of your target in your `Package.swift`**. In addition, whatever you replace `MyLibraryTests` with must match the name of your test target in `Package.swift`.

You should put all of your source files in the `MyLibrary` directory (or whatever you rename it).

Here's an example `Package.swift` file that I think will match your project setup.

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyLibrary", targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyLibrary", dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(name: "MyLibraryTests", dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ]
)
```

Once you have moved your source files and changed your `Package.swift`, you can just run `swift build`. Your library should be built somewhere in the `.build` folder (which will be created). It varies by computer, but mine is `.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/MyLibrary.build/`.

If you want specifically a static library, change this line:

```
.library(name: "MyLibrary", targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
```

to this:

```
.library(name: "MyLibrary", type: .static, targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
```